# Applying multiple conditions in a Python loop fails for unknown reason

Tags: python

I'm working through an 'easy' HackerRank exercise, and I'm trying to apply multiple conditions to items in a list. The 'solution' I attempted appears consistent with others discussed on the site, but does not work. I am interested in learning why it fails, because I cannot discern my error.

The purpose of the function is to count the valleys along a person's walk. The relative elevations of the walk are stored in a string (ie. 'DDUU' for down, down, up, up). The walk begins and finishes at sea level. The function accepts the number of steps 'n' and the route string. In the case above, it should return v = 1, and in fact, it does. However, when I run this on longer cases, the function's returns are incorrect.

```
def countingValleys(n, s):
    valleys = 0
    position = 0
    positions = []
    for step in s:    
        if step == 'U':
            position += 1
        else:
            position -= 1
        positions.append(position)
    for position in positions:
        if positions[position] < 0 and positions[position+1] == 0:
            valleys += 1
    return valleys
s = 'DDUUUUDDDDUUDDUU'
v = countingValleys(16, s)
```

In this case, len(s) = 16 and the number of valleys is 3, but the number returned is 4. I'm trying to understand the error. Examples of new code are appreciated, but I mostly want to know what is wrong within the code above and how that might be adjusted. I am hoping to better understand multiple conditions, not just fix the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried debugging it and seeing what's happening?

Comment: What exactly is the definition of a "valley"? As far as I can tell, your code considers any point just below sea level with the following point at sea level as a valley. But one could also consider something like `3 2 3` as a valley, i.e. any point where the path goes from down to up, or in other words any occurrence of `DU` in the input string.

Comment: If ```s``` are the steps, you don't need to pass ```n``` since ```len(s)``` already defines the number of steps.

Comment: @mkreiger I should have been clearer: A 'valley' a course of any length that is continuously below 0.

Comment: @accdias I've simply shared the problem as I found it, and ncica's answer below clarifies why I need the 'n', which wasn't intuitive to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of :

```
    for position in positions:
        if positions[position] < 0 and positions[position+1] == 0:
            valleys += 1
```

you need:

```
    for i in range(n):
        if positions[i] < 0 and positions[i+1] == 0:
            valleys += 1
```

Comment: Great. This works. However, it still is not clear to me why my answer did not. Can you elaborate as the reason those are interpreted differently by the computer?

Comment: Yours doesn't work because your are indexing the ```positions``` array using one of its values (those stored in ```position```) and  not one of its indexes.

Comment: Aren't you getting an ```IndexError: list index out of range``` using this solution? I think you are going to have something like that because of ```positions[i+1]``` and ```range(n)```. In your example, where ```n=16``` you are going to refer to ```positions[16]``` which doesn't exist.

Comment: Because of if statement its working, it will not work in special cases, in that cases he can put some exceptions @accdias

Answer (score -1):

The following lines of code are erroneous:

```
for position in positions:
        if positions[position] < 0 and positions[position+1] == 0:
```

And I suppose you wanted to have something like:

```
for i in range(len(positions)-1):
        if positions[position] < 0 and positions[position+1] == 0:
```

For example: If you have the following
s = `'DDDUUU'`, then your positions array looks like this: `[-1, -2, -3, -2, -1, 0]` and you will check `position[-2]` two times: (position[-2] is the 2nd value of positions read from the right and is -1.)

Both times your if will evaluated to true and thus you get two values and this is surely not intended.

Comment: I would really appreciate to know, why my answer has been down voted. If someone has an issue with it, please state so in the comments and it can be improved.